# ASP.NET page published on IIS 7 reports 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get an ASP.NET MVC 4 page working on a productive system. On my local system with IIS 7 and Windows 7 Professional everything works fine.

Productive system:

- Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64 bit
- IIS 7 with .NET 4

For the page I created a new IIS site. For the site i created a new application pool which uses: .NET Framework v4.0.30319 and integrated mode. For the application pool the flag for 32 bit applications is activated, because i need to run my application as 32 bit app.

When I access the page via

```
https://localhost:12345/PageName
```

i get the error message:

(I translate it from german:)
    Server error in application /PageName
    The resource could not be found

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource or a dependency could not be found...
Requested URL: /PageName

Version: .NET 4.0.30319; ASP.NET 4.0.30319.1
```

The routing table:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

The Index method of the controller looks like this

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[RequireHttps(Order = 1)]
public ActionResult Index(string method, string chapterId, string sessionKey, string cn, string ui, string pw, string ProductNumber, string DocumentData)
{
    // something...
}
```

web.config

```
...
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0" />

     <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms protection="All" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" />
     </authentication>

     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

     <sessionState mode="Off" />
</system.web>
...
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />

  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

For debugging purpose I added the http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx to the Application_Start function of the global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    // added call here
}
```

The route is solved correct. --> Controller = "MyController", Action = "Index", Id = ""

IIS log

```
2012-12-12 15:21:04 ::1 GET /PageName - 49266 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 404 0 0 656
2012-12-12 15:32:18 ::1 GET /PageName - 49266 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 404 0 0 0
2012-12-12 15:37:48 ::1 GET /PageName - 49266 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 404 0 0 5687
```

Windows EventLog doesnt show anything more.

Comment: Is `PageName` the name of the application you created in IIS? Or is it the name of some controller you are trying to reach?

Comment: PageName is the virtual directory of the IIS